# Typeorm: ManyToOne relationship with composite key failing with "Referenced column eventId was not found in entity UserToEvent"

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am unable to create a new relation to my entity with composite primary key.

This is the entity:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'user_events_event' })
export class UserToEvent {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number
    
    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.events, { primary: true })
    user: User
    
    @ManyToOne(() => Event, (event) => event.users, { primary: true })
    event: Event
    
    // what I am trying to add:
    @OneToMany(() => TrainingNoteEntity, (trainingNote) => trainingNote.participation)
    trainingNotes: Array<TrainingNoteEntity>
}
```

And the new entity:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'training-note' })
export class TrainingNoteEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number
    
    @ManyToOne(() => UserToEvent)
    @JoinColumn([
        { name: 'id', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
        { name: 'eventId', referencedColumnName: 'eventId' },
        { name: 'user', referencedColumnName: 'userId' },
    ])
    participation: UserToEvent
}
```

On the `ManyToOne` clause I would normally add the `key` only, but this generates an error stating that the entity can't be referenced fully
So I added the `@JoinColumn` referencing all primary keys.
The migrations are not generating due to an error

`Referenced column eventId was not found in entity UserToEvent`

I tried to change eventId -> event and userId -> user, but I get the same error.

Comment: In the ```UserToEvent``` class you have already a **unique** primary key that uniquely identify your entity. Remove the ```{ parimary: true }``` from both ```user``` and ```event``` field. It's simplier and cleaner (most of the time), however I want to suggest [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188995/are-composite-primary-keys-bad-practice). **Or** remove the ```id```: "a user can participate to the same event at most once".

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I did take it. Removing `primary: true` also appeared to be hard. I needed to remove the compound index with `CASCADE` clause. I did take real data and perform a dry run. Seems that adding cascade to index removal doesn't make any difference. I also need to ensure all inserts and selects work, but I think they should without a problem. Thanks again